# #VALUE error when returning average or "" to cell with function

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have the following VBA Code:

```
Function AvgNoColor(rngData As Range, color As String) As Variant

Dim sum As Double
Dim amount As Double
Dim C As Range

    For Each C In rngData
        If color = "Red" Then
            If Not COLORINDEX(C) = 44 And Not COLORINDEX(C) = 3 Then
                sum = sum + C.Value
                amount = amount + 1
            Else
    'HERE
                AvgNoColor = ""
            End If
        ElseIf color = "Orange" Then
            If Not COLORINDEX(C) = 44 Then
                sum = sum + C.Value
                amount = amount + 1
            Else
    'HERE
                AvgNoColor = ""
            End If
        End If
    Next

AvgNoColor = sum / amount

End Function
```

Simply put, I want the average of the cells within a range that aren't color "Red"  or "Orange". The averages are returned as expected, but when a cell needs to be empty, the cell gets the `#VALUE` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By putting this line (`AvgNoColor = sum / amount`) outside the if-else blocks, you've opened your code to division by zero/undefined, which will throw errors in every directions if triggered.

Try this revision:

```
Function AvgNoColor(rngData As Range, color As String) As Variant

Dim sum As Double
Dim amount As Double
Dim C As Range

    For Each C In rngData
        If color = "Red" Then
            If Not COLORINDEX(C) = 44 And Not COLORINDEX(C) = 3 Then
                sum = sum + C.Value
                amount = amount + 1
            End If
        ElseIf color = "Orange" Then
            If Not COLORINDEX(C) = 44 Then
                sum = sum + C.Value
                amount = amount + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

If sum <> 0 And amount <> 0 Then 
    AvgNoColor = sum / amount
Else
    AvgNoColor = ""
End If

End Function
```

Comment: It does work but I had to change the variables sum and amount to variants because a double can't be "" so it gave an error again. Works fine now, thanks!

Comment: That is an oversight on my behalf. I'll correct it. If this worked for you, you should indicate this by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: Apologies, I only intended to inform in case you were not aware. Cheers and happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Try ISERROR(value) function:

```
If Not IsError(AvgNoColor) Then
    'your code
End If
```

If value is an error value (#N/A, #VALUE!, #REF!, #DIV/0!, #NUM!, #NAME? or #NULL), this function will return TRUE. Otherwise, it will return FALSE.

Comment: I tried putting the `IsError` before the `For Each` and after the `AvgNoColor = sum / amount`, and commanded out the `AvgNoColor = ""`, but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: By saying "but when a cell needs to be empty, the cell gets the #VALUE error", do you mean the #VALUE is displayed for your result i.e. Average?

Comment: I mean the cell in the worksheets gets #VALUE in stead of being empty

Comment: While diplaying AvgNoColor write:
Sub demo()
    If Not IsError(Cells(1, 4).Value) Then
        'your code
        Cells(1, 1) = AvgNoColor  'replace Cells(1,1) with your cell address
    Else
        Cells(1, 1) = ""  'this inserts empty string
    End If
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

pls try in cells

```
=IF(ISERROR(AvgNoColor(A3:A14,"Red"))="FALSE",AvgNoColor(A3:A14,"Red"),"")
```

Comment: For some reason now all my cells are being empty except for the cells that should be